# gnuplot -- how can i use the first value of the column im plotting?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, fixed

i have a data file that looks like this:

```
#processors    timea     timeb
1              45        150
2              25         80
3              13.43      60.2
4              10         40
5              8          38
6              7          35
7              6.5        34.2
8              5          32
```

I need to plot the corresponding speedup curves, which is basically

```
plot 'datapoints.dat' u $1:((first_valc1/$2)),\
     'datapoints.dat' u $1:((first_valc2/$3))
```

the variables "first_valc1" and ""first_valc2" should be the first values of the column im plotting, that is 45 and 150 respectively.

How i can do this automatically without hardcoding the numbers?? The idea is to use the same script for many data files.

Answer (score 4):

I answer myself,

```
first_valc1=system("awk 'FNR == 1 {print $2}' datapoints.dat")
first_valc2=system("awk 'FNR == 1 {print $3}' datapoints.dat")
```